# Is there any MAC like hmac-sha2-256-96 mac in openssh?

Tags: hmac, openssh

I used this command

```
$ ssh username@ip_addr -m hmac-sha2-256-96
```

but I got this message: `unknown type mac`

Is there any MAC like this or is it really not valid?

Comment: If the command rejects it, then it doesn't recognise it. Did you read the man pages to see what hmacs are accepted? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

Comment: yes i read man page also i check through command like ssh -Q mac but i did not find it.

Comment: right, so, there is no MAC like that and it is invalid ...

Comment: but i got some like because of that i am confuse. i will share with that link        https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/secsh/current/msg00517.html

Comment: and tell me is really not available or is it typing mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such MAC. The list of available MACs can be queried using `ssh -q mac`:

```
$ ssh -Q mac
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
hmac-ripemd160
hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

If I see right, you were trying to combine the `hmac-md5-96` with `hmac-sha2-256`, but it does not make any sense.

The last number says the length of the hash (why to specify it twice?), in the MD5 case truncated to 96 bit (out of 128 bit), but in the SHA2 case, the last number simply gives the length of the hash (because SHA2 has variable hash-length, not only truncation as the long broken MD5).

Comment: ohhk i find out everywhere but i did not get ans, so thanks for your answer